# variadic function - how to ensure parameters passed correctly

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

Is there any way (built-in or a code pattern) to ensure that a variadic function is passed the correct number of parameters?  (This will be included as part of an API obviously, I can check my own internal code.)

I was considering requiring a UN32 Magic Number to be the last argument passed and check that for validity in the variadic function. Does anyone have any thoughts on that?

Comment: What arguments are being passed? What benefit are you hoping to get from using a variadic function? Especially in C++ there are much better ways to do it, if safety is a concern, which it apparently is.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers.  There was something informative in every answer, I wish I could accept more than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [PP_NARG](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/browse_frm/thread/77ee8c8f92e4a3fb/346fc464319b1ee5) macro to add a count semi-automatically.

```
int myfunc (int count, ...);
#define MYFUNC(...) myfunc(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

MYFUNC(a,b,c,d);
MYFUNC(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
```

gcc -E produces:

```
int myfunc (int count, ...);

myfunc(4, a,b,c,d);
myfunc(7, a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
```

Comment: Note that, formally, this will require your function always accept at least one parameter, since the `__VA_ARGS__` list can not be empty, although I believe some preprocessors ignore this requirement. Its probably the best you can do in C, though, without moving away from a variadic function all together.

Comment: This seems to be the "cleverest" answer but I understand the limitations inherent to variadic functions more clearly now.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it handle zero arguments. `MYFUNC();` produces `myfunc(1, );` which is no good.

Answer (score 4):

`va_*` macros just pop the variables from the local stack, so you have to trust the user. passing an array/size tuple could be safer, I think.

Answer (score 3):

There is no definitive way in C or C++ to ensure that the correct number of arguments have been passed to a variadic function. Even requiring a signature is not guaranteed to work as it may clash with the value of a valid argument. You will probably be much better off passing a vector<> as the element count retrieved is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you use the variadic template feature of C++0x applied to a function? This would generate a vararg function that is type-safe .

See this link with it's type-safe printf implementation using a variadic templated function

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#variadic-templates

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "ensure that a variadic function is passed the correct number of parameters"...

Passing a UN32 Magic Number as last argument will allow you to determine where the list of arguments ends, so their overall number. So, by counting how many arguments you have found before UN32, you know how many arguments you have and your function should know whether is it enough. Don't know if it is ok for you to determine this at run-time (it could be too late)...

Anyway, usually variadic functions have a fixed argument list portion representing the mandatory arguments (at least one); so possibly this should be the way for you to ensure that the function gets the correct number of arguments...

Comment: Passing an UN32 (unsigned 32-bit integer?) Magic Number lets the caller *tell you* where the list of arguments ends.  It doesn't guarantee that the caller will do this correctly.  For example, the caller might pass the trailing magic number correctly, but pass something of the wrong type for an earlier argument.  It probably makes the user think a bit harder about getting the arguments right, but I don't think it buys you much.  Clearly document what's expected, and make it the caller's responsibility to get it right.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: I perfectly agree! make it a contract, then find ways to check that it has not been broken before the irreparable happens...

Comment: The problem is, there might not be any way to check that it hasn't been broken.  If I call `printf("%s\n", s)`, where s points to an array that don't contain a terminating '\0', there's no way that printf can detect that there's a problem; by the time printf is running, the irreparable has already happened.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not possible.

Variadic breaks type-safety in a way that cannot be fixed.

If you want type-safety back, then consider breaking variadic function into several typesafe 
member function of a [small] class that holds the shared state between their calls.

This is always possible, even if multiple calls might look awkward compared to single variadic 
call.

Shared state is probably why you wanted variadic function in the first place.

Take iostream vs  printf as example.